# Is there a software for plotting trending code coverage data from Karma/Jasmine

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, linechart, karma-coverage

I have an Angular app along with the standard Karma/Jasmine set up for unit testing. What I want is to feed the code coverage reports I get for each nightly build into a software that would create a trend of how my coverage is changing through time.

Does anybody know a product that can do that? My Google search didn't come up with anything.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: What is your CI tool?

Comment: It's a home brewed one, nothing main stream like Jenkins.